# Decode an array inside JSON data only using Swift 4 Codable

Tags: swift, swift4, codable

I'm using Swift 4 `Codable` and I'm receiving this JSON from my web service:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "time": "00:02:00",
        "employees": [
            {
                "id": 001,
                "name": "foo"
            }, 
            {
                "id": 002,
                "name": "bar"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to decode only employees array into employee objects (the time property will only be saved once), but nothing works.
I read a lot of materials about Swift 4 `Codable` but don't get how can I decode this array.

EDIT: My employee class:

```
import Foundation

struct Employee: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var time: Date

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case time = "time"
    }
}
```

The request:

```
  Alamofire.SessionManager.default.request(Router.syncUsers)
            .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])
            .responseJSON { response in
                if response.response?.statusCode == 200 {
        guard let jsonDict = response as? Dictionary<String, Any>,
                    let feedPage = Employee(from: jsonDict as! Decoder) else {
                    return
                }

                guard let response = response.result.value as? [String: Any] else {
                    return
                }

                guard let data = response["data"] as? [String: Any] else {
                    return
                }

                guard let users = data["employees"] else {
                    return
                }

                guard let usersData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: users, options: .prettyPrinted) else {
                    return
                }

                guard let decoded = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: usersData, options: []) else {
                    return
                }

                let decoder = JSONDecoder()

                guard let employee = try? decoder.decode(Employee.self, from: usersData) else {
                    print("errorMessage")
                    return
                }
                } else {
                    print("errorMessage")
                }
        }
```

Comment: Did you actually look at your code and the JSON response in your question? You're clearly looking for a key named `users` in your response, when your example response shows a key named `employees`. Moreover, your approach is clearly wrong. You already parse the response as JSON using `Alamofire`, then you reencode part of it to JSON just to be able to use `JSONDecoder` to decode it from `Data`. That makes no sense. Either do the whole JSON parsing in a type-safe manner using `Codable` and `JSONDecoder` or do it dynamically using `Alamofire`'s `responseJSON`.

Comment: sorry, the key is employees... i changed the json recently. but still doesnt work :/ could you post an example of an decode for that code. I know that this code doesnt make much sense, but I'm changing the code for the last hour and dont get success . this is a simple task I know, but I cant make it work yet :(

Comment: Numbers can't start with `0` in JSON (except for numbers in the range 0 <= x < 1), so `001` is not JSON.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using `Codable` you cannot decode inner data without decoding the outer.

But it's pretty simple, for example you can omit all CodingKeys.

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let status : String
    let data : EmployeeData
}

struct EmployeeData : Decodable {
    let time : String
    let employees : [Employee]
}

struct Employee: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}
```

---

```
let jsonString = """
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "time": "00:02:00",
        "employees": [
            {"id": 1, "name": "foo"},
            {"id": 2, "name": "bar"}
        ]
    }
}
"""


do {
    let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
    for employee in result.data.employees {
        print(employee.name, employee.id)
    }
} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: What's the difference between `Codable` and `Decodable`/`Encodable`?

Comment: The definition of `Codable` is `Decodable & Encodable` that means it conforms to both.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this kind of JSON parsing problem very easily with [quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io/?l=swift&gist=ed798bf41236c555ed1f1e0e1ccdfd73).  Just paste in your JSON on the left and you'll get types and serialization/deserialization code on the right, for a variety of languages.  Here are the types it produces for your JSON:

```
struct Employees: Codable {
    let status: String
    let data: EmployeesData
}

struct EmployeesData: Codable {
    let time: String
    let employees: [Employee]
}

struct Employee: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}
```